Is it possible to use a Nestjs standalone app in an Electron app using yarn workspaces?
I have a yarn monorepo consist of Nestjs and Electron projects. I needed to use Nestjs app as a dependecy in electron project. Is it possible? If it is how to configure both projects to achive it?
I tried to add nestjs app as a dependevy and export boostrap function but it dis not worked
